# ¿COMO VALIDAR UN REGISTRO SEGUN EL DIA REGISTRADO?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Hola Tengo un problema de una aplicación que hago en java (NEATBEANS CON MYSQL), es un programa de reservaciones. una de las actividades es tennis préstamo de canchas, hay 14 canchas re prestan todo el día 1 hr / 30 minutos, y tiene un cupo máximo de 8 personas, en mi base de datos tengo tablas que me ayudan a ver los registros diarios, el cupo máximo, el cupo restante por cancha y hora.

Lo que me hace falta es que valide el día y según ese día verifique cuanto cupo hay en "x" ese día, "x" cancha, "x" hora. por ejemplo un día lunes-12-10-2020 se me llenan mis reservaciones de todas mis canchas en todos los horarios, y alguien me pide reservar en martes-13-10-2020, quiero que valide si hay reservaciones en esa fecha y si no hay me mande a cupo disponible (8), y revise la hora y así sucesivamente! ya tengo las consultas que hacen validaciones, pero quiero lo de la fecha espero y me puedan ayudar!

EL EJEMPLO DEL CODIGO ESTA BASADO EN UNA CANCHA (Nº1) A UNA HORA (07:00)
BOTON AGREGAR

```
 private void btnagregarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    try{
            txtfechaactual.setText(FechaActual.fechaactual());
            Date date = fechaasis.getDate();
            canchas canchas = new canchas ();
            canchas.NumMembrecia = txtnummembrecia.getText();
            canchas.FechaReg = txtfechaactual.getText();
            canchas.Actividad = txtcanchas.getText();
            canchas.FechaAsistencia = date.toGMTString();
            canchas.Hora = (cbxhora.getSelectedItem().toString());
            canchas.Cancha = txtCanchas.getText();
            canchas.Integrantes = cbxintegrantes.getSelectedItem().toString();
            canchas.Estado = cbxestado.getSelectedItem().toString();
            canchas.comentarios = txtareadatos.getText();
            canchas.UserAmd = MenuPrincipal.lblnombrecompleto1.getText();
            RegistrarEnCancha();
                if (CanchasDAO.registroCancha(canchas)>0){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Se Agrego Con Èxito", "Cita Agregada", INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Folio Para La Cancha: " + canchas.Cancha + " Membrecia; " + canchas.NumMembrecia);
                    txtnummembrecia.setText("");
                    txtfechaactual.setText("");
                    //fechaasis.setDateFormatString("");
                    cbxhora.setSelectedItem("SELECCIONA");
                    txtCanchas.setText("SELECCIONA");
                    cbxintegrantes.setSelectedItem("SELECCIONA");
                    cbxestado.setSelectedItem("SELECCIONA");
                    txtareadatos.setText("");
                    }else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se Agrego Intenta Nuevamente o Ponte en Contacto Con el Administrador");
                    }
                    actualizarTable();
                    txtfechaactual.setText(FechaActual.fechaactual());

            
    }
        catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "NO TIENES LOS DATOS CORRECTOS", "ERROR", INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
    
}              

 public void RegistrarEnCancha(){
    ValidarMem();
    Hdao.CupoMAX();
    Disponibilidad();
    int M = m.Membrecia;
    String EstMem = m.Estatus;
    int rm = Integer.parseInt(txtnummembrecia.getText());
    if (rm == M){
        if (EstMem == "ACCESO"){
            Hdao.RegistroUCancha();
        }else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "LA MEMBRECIA NO TIENE ACCESO");   
        }
    }else 
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "LA MEMBRECIA NO EXISTE");
    }
    

}

    public void ValidarMem (){
    Membrecias M = new Membrecias ();
    int NM = Integer.parseInt(txtnummembrecia.getText());
    Connection con = null;
    Statement st = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try{
        con = conexion.abrirconexion();
        st = con.createStatement();
        String sql="SELECT * FROM permisosmembrecias WHERE MEMBRECIA=" +NM;
        rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
        while(rs.next()){
            M.Estatus = rs.getString("ESTATUS");
            M.Membrecia = rs.getInt("MEMBRECIA");
        }
    }catch(SQLException ex){
        Logger.getLogger(MembreciasDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }finally{
    try{
         con.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MembreciasDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    
     try{
         st.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MembreciasDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }       
    }
        
        
}

public  void CupoMAX(){
    Connection con = null;
    Statement st = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {

        con = conexion.abrirconexion();
        st = con.createStatement();
        String sql = "select * from cupomax";
        rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
        while(rs.next()){
            MaxCancha1 = rs.getInt("Cancha1");
            MaxCancha2 = rs.getInt("Cancha2");
            MaxCancha3 = rs.getInt("Cancha3");
            MaxCancha4 = rs.getInt("Cancha4");
            MaxCancha5 = rs.getInt("Cancha5");
            MaxCancha6 = rs.getInt("Cancha6");
            MaxCancha7 = rs.getInt("Cancha7");
            MaxCancha8 = rs.getInt("Cancha8");
            MaxCancha9 = rs.getInt("Cancha9");
            MaxCancha10 = rs.getInt("Cancha10");
            MaxCancha11 = rs.getInt("Cancha11");
            MaxCancha12 = rs.getInt("Cancha12");
            MaxCancha13 = rs.getInt("Cancha13");
            MaxCancha14 = rs.getInt("Cancha14");
     
        }
    }catch (SQLException ex){
        Logger.getLogger(HorariosDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    finally {
        try{
            con.close();
        }catch (SQLException e){
        Logger.getLogger(HorariosDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);    
        }
        try{
            st.close();
        }catch (SQLException e){
        Logger.getLogger(HorariosDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);    
        }
        try{
            rs.close();
        }catch (SQLException e){
        Logger.getLogger(HorariosDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);    
        }
    }       
}

public void Disponibilidad(){ 
    Connection con = null;
    Statement st = null;
    System.out.println("CANCHA "+ validarCancha);   // SOLO PRUEBA PARA VER DATOS  
    System.out.println(validarCancha);             //  SOLO PRUEBA PARA VER DATOS
            try {
            con = conexion.abrirconexion();
            st = con.createStatement();
            String sql = "select * from registroscanchashora where IDCancha = '"+validarCancha+"'";
            rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
            while(rs.next()){
                Hdao.Cupo1 = rs.getInt("hora1");
                Hdao.Cupo2 = rs.getInt("hora2");
                Hdao.Cupo3 = rs.getInt("hora3");
                Hdao.Cupo4 = rs.getInt("hora4");
                Hdao.Cupo5 = rs.getInt("hora5");
                Hdao.Cupo6 = rs.getInt("hora6");
                Hdao.Cupo7 = rs.getInt("hora7");
                Hdao.Cupo8 = rs.getInt("hora8");
                Hdao.Cupo9 = rs.getInt("hora9");
                Hdao.Cupo10 = rs.getInt("hora10");     
            }
                System.out.println("cupo DE HORA 1 = "+Hdao.Cupo1); //SOLO PRUEBA PARA VER DATOS
        }catch (SQLException ex){
            Logger.getLogger(HorariosDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        finally {
            try{
                con.close();
            }catch (SQLException e){
            Logger.getLogger(HorariosDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);    
            }
            try{
                st.close();
            }catch (SQLException e){
            Logger.getLogger(HorariosDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);    
            }
            try{
                rs.close();
            }catch (SQLException e){
            Logger.getLogger(HorariosDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);    
            }
        }

}

public void RegistroUCancha(){
    CupoMAX();
    I = Integer.parseInt(canchas.Integrantes); 
    C = Integer.parseInt(canchas.Cancha);
    Connection con = null;
    Statement st = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    switch (C){
        case 1:
            if (Cupo1 <=  MaxCancha1){
                if (I <= Cupo1){
                    
                    try {
                    con = conexion.abrirconexion();
                    st = con.createStatement();
                    String sql = "UPDATE registroscanchashora  SET hora1='"+I+"' WHERE IDCancha='"+C+"'";
                    rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
                    while(rs.next()){
                        Cupo1 = rs.getInt("hora1");
                    }
                    
                }catch (SQLException ex){
                    Logger.getLogger(HorariosDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                finally {
                    try{
                        con.close();
                    }catch (SQLException e){
                    Logger.getLogger(HorariosDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);    
                    }
                    try{
                        st.close();
                    }catch (SQLException e){
                    Logger.getLogger(HorariosDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);    
                    }
                    try{
                        rs.close();
                    }catch (SQLException e){
                    Logger.getLogger(HorariosDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);    
                    }
                }        
                        }else{
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "EXCEDE EL CUPO DISPONIBLE");    
                        }                        
                    }
                    else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "NO HAY CUPO");
                    }
            cupores = MaxCancha1 - Cupo1;
            System.out.println(cupores);
        break;        
    }
}
```

CAPTURAS DE BASE DE DATOS
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, Bienvenidx a SOes. Es muuuuy difícil que las personas se pongan a la tarea de replicar tus problemas con los datos y las consultas en imágenes. Entiendo que nos quieres explicar, pero piensa en qué va a pasar si te respondemos con imágenes, te ponemos a transcribir y te salen errores porque la letra está muy pequeña, no se entiende o es mucho código. PD. Evita la myúscula sostenida; se asimila a gritos y por tu pregunta sé que no es la idea pero es ideal que lo evites.

Comment: Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes. Recuerda que puedes editar siempre tus preguntas usando el enlace Editar que esta justo bajo la pregnta y las etiquetas

Comment: no termino de entender tu problema en semejante cantidad de codigo.. pero luego de ver tus bases de datos, te recomendaria que leas sobre normalizacion de bases de datos. tal vez por eso tengas problemas...

Comment: Hola es mucho codigo porque tome còdigo que esta en otras clases! para que funcione lo que quiero es que cuando registre una persona a una hora en x cance x fecha se guarde, pero si registro otro dia no me siga tomando las del mismo dia anterior no se si me explico!